# Hide form labels with CSS on "My Account Page -> Addresses"

Tags: css, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Please [check on this picture](https://imgur.com/a/zbZ5kwK) for a betther understanding.

I could hide the input field for **Población field** which is actualy the `shipping_city`,
for this purpose I used:

```
#shipping_city {
    display: none;
}
```

**and works!**

However, I can not hide the label **Población**

I tried:

```
label[for="shipping_city"] {
display: none;
}
```

With no success

Comment: Without seeing the relevant HTML it is impossible to give an answer that isn't just a guess.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I put a link to see the code, does it help?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask we need to see relevant code as code, not on an external site and not as an image.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved, the user below understood the explanation I gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your label tag show with script.
So, add '!important' at your css, like this code.

```js
$("label[for='shipping_code']").show();
```

```css
label[for="shipping_code"]{
  display:none;           /* not_woriking */
  display:none!important; /* woriking*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="shopping_code">test</label>
```